# Using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm pretty new to cocos2d and am having a bit of trouble using NSUserDefaults to store and retrieve user-specific data.

In the game that I am making, the user is a fisherman who upgrades his gear by earning coins. For example, the fishing rod has a certain power that can be upgraded as a player progresses in the game.

I have found it easy enough to store and retrieve value from UserDefaults, but I can't figure out how to set the initial value for a fishing rod's power and to not have that value reset the fishing rod power every time the game is turned on.

Even when the user upgrades the rod, the next time they play the game their rod power will reset because the program will go back through the same code that set the initial value.

I would love to find a way to set the initial value and never have to set it again.

Answer (score 2):

Only set the initial value if one does not already exist for that particular key. Where ever the initial value is set, try this instead:

```
id object = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"rodPower"];

if (!object) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:<initialValue> forKey:"rodPower"]; 
}
```

That way if you have already saved a value for that key, the initial value will not be set again.

Comment: Don't forget to call [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; to save your changes.

Comment: @NicholasHart You do not need to call `synchronize`. It will be done for you.

Comment: An even better approach is to use `NSUserDefaults registerDefaults` to set default values. Much easier than checking to see if values exist or not.

Comment: @rmaddy True, but from the docs: "The synchronize method, which is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, keeps the in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults database."  Personally I find it convenient to invoke synchronize when I'm done updating user defaults so that I know my data is preserved in case the app gets terminated.